# To get object from array based on condition

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, contains

In my application I am having entity class like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface classAbc : NSObject
{
    NSString *strTitle;
    int iId;


}

@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSString *strTitle;
@property(nonatomic) int iId;
@end
```

and in my NSMutableArray I am storing objects of this class like:

```
classAbc *objAbc=[[classAbc alloc] init];
objAbc.iId=1;
objAbc.strTitle=@"Title 1";

classAbc *objAbc1=[[classAbc alloc] init];
objAbc1.iId=2;
objAbc1.strTitle=@"Title 2";

NSMutableArray *arrTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:objAbc,objAbc1,nil];

[objAbc release];
[objAbc1 release];
```

and now runtime I want to retrieve Object from this array based on objAbc.iId condition like:

if arrTemp contains object having its iId value as 2 for example.

Can any one suggest way other than for loop iteration? As number objects can increase for loop will take lot of time to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Au contraire, for loops are quite fast.  Unless you'll be looping through 100's of objects, it is absolutely not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I got answer to this question. Using NSPredicate is the best way for such condition. Using NSPredicate we can apply condition on any member of the class object.

This is link for MAC OS X however this works on iPhone sdk with some changes. 
[NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use NSMutableDictionary for storing your object where the key is the object's id and the value is the object itself. If you don't mind for the order use this approach.

```
classAbc *objAbc=[[classAbc alloc] init];
objAbc.iId=1;
objAbc.strTitle=@"Title 1";

classAbc *objAbc1=[[classAbc alloc] init];
objAbc1.iId1=2;
objAbc1.strTitle1=@"Title 2";


NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:objAbc1 forKey:objAbc1.iId1];

.
.
.

classAbc *abc = (classAbc*)[dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

**Note** : change id from type int to type NSNumber so you can store it as a key

Comment: giorashc , thanks for you quick reply but here I have just given example of id the matching condition can be on any member of object. So i don't think this will be helpful.

Comment: Any two objects can be compared so I don't see why you should not use a dictionary for your purpose. Custom objects can override the `isEqual` and `hash` methods for custom comparison.

Comment: I do not want to compare two object I want to find a single object based on condition on any member of that object.

Comment: Can you pseudo code an example to what you mean by "condition on any member of that object" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use predicateWithBlock: to get the object of specific property.
[NSPredicate Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

- (NSPredicate *)predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings))block

Answer (score 0):

You could kook at filteredArrayUsingPredicate: but to be honest that's probably just doing fast enumeration in the background.

Make sure your "for loop" is actually a fast enumeration loop rather than using the count of the array as a loop integer:

```
for (classAbc* obj in arrTemp)
{
    // check for your match
    break; // if found
}
```

Only try something more complex if this actually gives you measurable performance problems.

Comment: jrturton, Yes I am aware of this. This is my last choice if I do not get any other solution for faster iteration.